# Atom Editor Not Reading All The Snippets in Snippets.cson

Tags: coffeescript, atom-editor

My snippets.cson:-

```
'*':
  'WordPress theme directory':
    'prefix': 'wpThemeDirectoryUri'
    'body': """
    get_template_directory_uri()
        """

'*':
  'WordPress Site URL (No Trailing Slash)':
    'prefix': 'wpSiteUrl'
    'body': """
      site_url()
        """
```

In the editor, when I press `alt + shift + s` hotkey to search for available snippets and type "wp", it lists only `wpSiteUrl`.

Should not it also list `wpThemeDirectoryUri`?

If I remove second snippet. It lists `wpThemeDirectoryUri`.

I've big snippets and your solution must support multiline snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading @lee-dohm answer at:-

[Atom Editor: multiple snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615818/atom-editor-multiple-snippets/26635125#26635125)

I found the solution:-

```
'*':
  'WordPress theme directory':
    'prefix': 'wpThemeDirectoryUri'
    'body': """
    get_template_directory_uri()
        """

  'WordPress Site URL (No Trailing Slash)':
    'prefix': 'wpSiteUrl'
    'body': """
      site_url()
        """
```