# Atom snippets: Multiple line snippets in atom editor

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, atom-editor, code-snippets

I recently switched to Atom text editor for programming from Geany text editor. I have lots of python snippets in geany. In geany writing snippets is super easy.

For example:

```
# for geany text editor (snippets.conf file)  
h=# Author : Bhishan Poudel\n# Date   : {date}\n
```

If I type h and then hit enter, i will get the above snippet with current time.

**How can we do so in ATOM?**

My attempt so far is this:
I edited the snippets.cson file like this:

```
'.source.python':
  'example1':
    'prefix': 'h'
    'body': '
      #!/usr/bin/env python\n
      # -*- coding: utf-8\n
      #\nDate: {date}\n
      #Imports\n
      import numpy as np
      '
```

But, this did not work well.

Related links are:
[Atom editor: snippet for inserting a timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669615/atom-editor-snippet-for-inserting-a-timestamp?rq=1)
http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/snippets/
[Atom Editor: multiple snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615818/atom-editor-multiple-snippets?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a solution for the multiline part of your question and a suggestion for the naming. What i did was this:

```
'.source.python':
  'header and imports for python':
    'prefix': 'pyhead'
    'body':"""
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  # -*- coding: utf-8
  #Date: $1
  #Imports
  import numpy as np
  $2
  """
```

the `$1` indicates, that you jump to this is after the snipped is inserted. So that way you could file in the date yourself (not optimal I know). The `$2` will be the place for the next TAB key. The other part is, that you use a prefix which is easy to identify.
The multiline part is done with the `"""` at the beginning and end of the body so everything should be inserted smoothly

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve multiline problem with using `"""` in body explanation of your snippet.

For instance:

```
'.source.python':
  'DATA SCIENCE':
    'prefix':'data_import'
    'body':"""import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns"""
```